# Javascript - Making an object and incrementing count in an array for each loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an object from a `forEach` loop in javascript and in this simple object, I am trying to add up all of the `count`s for each item in the array.

Currently, I'm using firebase in an ionic (angular/typescript) project and I am returning an array of items from firebase.  The array looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        id:'uniqueID',
        specs: {
            count:5,
            forSale:false,
            group:"qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
            name:"Foxeer Cam 2",
            type:"camera"
        }
    },
    {
        id:'uniqueID',
        specs: {
            count:4,
            forSale:false,
            group:"qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
            name:"Furibee 40a",
            type:"esc"
        }
    },
    {
        id:'uniqueID',
        specs: {
            count:4,
            forSale:false,
            group:"qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
            name:"Runcam Cam 1",
            type:"camera"
        }
    },
    {
        id:'uniqueID',
        specs: {
            count:1,
            forSale:false,
            group:"qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
            name:"Hobbywing 4 in 1",
            type:"esc"
        }
    }
]
```

Here's how I'm running through these items (`result` being the list of items):

```
let partArr = [];
let typeObj = {};
result.forEach(part => {

  //Put all parts in a list
  partArr.push({
    'id':part.id,
    'specs':part.data(),
  });

  //Put all types in a list
  typeObj[part.data().type] = {
    'count': 0
  };

});
```

Now, I need to increment the count, adding each part's count to the last depending on their type.  The `typeObj` should look something like this.

```
{
    esc: {
        count:5
    },
    camera: {
        count:10
    }
}
```

I tried adding the count to the count like so:

```
  typeObj[part.data().type] = {
    'count': typeObj[part.data().type].count + part.data().count
  };
```

but it does not recognize there being a count when I'm first making the object. (I think).

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` to accomplish this since you want to transform an array into a single object:

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 'uniqueID',
    specs: {
      count: 5,
      forSale: false,
      group: "qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
      name: "Foxeer Cam 2",
      type: "camera"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'uniqueID',
    specs: {
      count: 4,
      forSale: false,
      group: "qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
      name: "Furibee 40a",
      type: "esc"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'uniqueID',
    specs: {
      count: 4,
      forSale: false,
      group: "qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
      name: "Runcam Cam 1",
      type: "camera"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'uniqueID',
    specs: {
      count: 1,
      forSale: false,
      group: "qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
      name: "Hobbywing 4 in 1",
      type: "esc"
    }
  }
];
const typeObj = array.reduce((obj, { specs: { count, type } }) => {
  obj[type] = obj[type] || { count: 0 };
  obj[type].count += count;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(typeObj);
```

What this does is assign `obj[type]` to either itself or if it doesn't yet exist, a new object `{ count: 0 }`. Then it increments the `count` property of `obj[type]` by the specified count in the data.

If you have a `data` method that returns an object with the data (as you seem to have in the question), you can modify it like so:

```
const typeObj = array.reduce((obj, item) => {
  const { type, count } = item.data().specs;
  obj[type] = obj[type] || { count: 0 };
  obj[type].count += count;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(typeObj);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I'm trying to get this running, but I'm only getting `undefined`.  I took a look at the array again and it's a bit different than I thought it was.  I've updated my question above if you're still available to help.  Again, thank you for the info!

Comment: @ntgCleaner Sure. I've updated my answer. You can just destructure one more level.

Comment: Thank you!! I couldn't understand where I was supposed to break down the children in the object, but that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to use `reduce` to generate the object with the counts all at once, and to call `.data()` only once on each iteration:

```js
const results = [
  {
    data() { return { specs: {
    count:5,
    forSale:false,
    group:"qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
    name:"Foxeer Cam 2",
    type:"camera"
  }}}},
  {
    data() { return { specs: {
    count:4,
    forSale:false,
    group:"qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
    name:"Furibee 40a",
    type:"esc"
  }}}},
  {
    data() { return { specs: {
    count:4,
    forSale:false,
    group:"qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
    name:"Runcam Cam 1",
    type:"camera"
  }}}},
  {
    data() { return { specs: {
    count:1,
    forSale:false,
    group:"qPELnTnwGJEtJexgP2qX",
    name:"Hobbywing 4 in 1",
    type:"esc"
  }}}}
];
const typeObj = results.reduce((a, item) => {
  const { count, type } = item.data().specs;
  if (!a[type]) a[type] = { count: 0 };
  a[type].count += count;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(typeObj);
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this running, but I'm only getting `undefined`. I took a look at the array again and it's a bit different than I thought it was. I've updated my question above if you're still available to help. Again, thank you for the info!

Comment: Where does `.data()` come from? I was extrapolating from your code that `data()` was an immediate property on each object, but I don't see it in your object structure at all even after the update? (Try posting your exact input in your question *when you post your question*)

Comment: If `specs` is on the object returned by `data`, then just do `const { count, type } = item.data().specs;` instead

Comment: `data()` comes from firestore, I use a path snapshot `this.store.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('parts').ref.onSnapshot(result => {}` to return `result`.  to get the data, you just run a `forEach` loop on result: `result.forEach(part => { console.log(part.data());}` (shown in the third line of the javascript above)

Comment: Also, _thanks for the tip_.  I mistyped my data and I apologize for not typing it correctly, although it's not extremely important, just trying to figure out how to access the object's children.